# Cannot start Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

when start kafka-consumer zookeeper display this:

```
[2019-01-02 16:34:15,893] INFO Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:51155 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2019-01-02 16:34:15,893] WARN Exception causing close of session 0x0: null (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
[2019-01-02 16:34:15,893] INFO Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:51155 (no session established for client) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
```

what happened to it,and how to solve ?

this is all my steps:

```
wget http://mirror.bit.edu.cn/apache/kafka/2.1.0/kafka_2.12-2.1.0.tgz
tar zxf kafka_2.12-2.1.0.tgz

cat config/zookeeper.properties | grep -Ev '^$|^#' >> config/zk.properties
cat config/server.properties | grep -Ev '^$|^#' >> config/kfk1.properties

bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zk.properties
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/kfk1.properties

bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic maoge --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --zookeeper localhost:2181
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:2181 --topic maoge --from-beginning
```

Comment: show the steps that you are following ?

Comment: Please be more elaborate while asking for a solution. Adding the details of your `server.properties` and the command/config you used for starting the kafka-consumer would help. Also, which consumer are you using? Is it a console consumer, or a consumer in some other language (Java, Python etc.)?

Comment: Did you check the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using zookeeper reference (port 2181) in the console consumer, with `bootstrap-server` which is incorrect. Kafka consumer used to have `--zookeeper` option, but has moved away from that config long time back, and now refers to broker for consumer.

The correct command for that would be something like: `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic maoge --from-beginning`

Comment: In that you would you mind accepting the answer if it solved your issue?